# createprocess suspended by default

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I have this function inside a dll:

```
int createChildProcess()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    int res;

    si.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    STARTUPINFO* ptr=&si;
    if(!CreateProcess(L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", NULL, 0, 0, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        mylog << "CreateProcess error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        res = 0;
    }
    else
        res = pi.dwProcessId;

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    return res;
}
```

And i found 2 problems:

1) The first time the function is called, return always error code 87 (The parameter is incorrect.).

2) The second time, the function works, but creates a child process in suspended status and the cpu usage in the father process goes to 100%.

Im testing with winXP sp3, and my dll was compiled in vs 2010.

any help?

Comment: The only thing you initialized in your `STARTUPINFO` structure is the `cb` member. The rest is uninitialized garbage. The results will be unpredictable.

Comment: mmm so you think is the STARTUPINFO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have initialized the `cbSize` field of your `STARTUPINFO` structure, but you've left the rest uninitialized. The first time you call `CreateProcess`, the uninitialized values are evidently *so wrong* that the function recognizes that they're wrong and gives up. You were *lucky*.

The second time you call it, the values are apparently such that the `CreateProcess` thinks you have asked it to do something it knows how to do, and so it proceeds. Such is the nature of undefined behavior.

To fix this, initialize *all* of the struct:

```
STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFO)};
```

Comment: Ok, I made some changes adding your sugestion ,and now the errror code is 1 all the time.

Comment: Maybe it's because you're telling it to create a new console for a non-console program. But that's beyond the scope of this question, which was about why the process was suspended.

Comment: you are right. thanks Rob.